# Access a cell by name using the `spreadsheet` gem

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet-gem

If I have a `sheet` variable that is of type `Spreadsheet::Excel::Worksheet`, right now we access `B2` by doing:

```
MY_CUSTOM_CELL = [1, 1]
sheet[*MY_CUSTOM_CELL] # => Contents of B2
```

In LibreOffice (And I'm sure Excel), I can assign a name for that cell in the "Name Box". See the image below, I've given B2 a name of "CUSTOM_NAME".

[image: Giving a cell a custom name using the "Name Box"]

Instead of accessing the contents of that cell using the row/column coordinates, **is it possible to access it via the name**? This would make it easier to adapt to future change if the cell changes location. I'd like to do something like:

```
sheet.find("CUSTOM_NAME") # => Contents of B2
```

I was looking at the documentation found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-spreadsheet/Spreadsheet/Worksheet) but was unable to find what I was looking for.

If the gem doesn't allow it already, how would I go about implementing it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the other answer may be a good alternative (I have not personally unverified), the answer to this question is **no**.

[Spreadsheet Issue - Feature - Retrieve a cell by its name, not just row and column](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/177#issuecomment-231329313)

There currently is no way to retrieve a cell by its name using the spreadsheet gem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with the *creek* gem, which is much faster than the *spreadsheet* gem when parsing large xlsx files.

```
require 'creek'

workbook = Creek::Book.new some_file.xlsx # Change the file name to suit your needs
worksheet = workbook.sheets[0] # Change the worksheet index to suit your needs. 

# Create hash with cell names (e.g., A1, B5) as keys and cell values as values
cells = Hash.new
  worksheet.rows.each do |row|
    cells.merge!(row)
  end
end

# To access the cell values, just use the corresponding hash keys

# Set value for the A1 cell
cells["A1"] = "foo"

# Print value of C3 cell
puts cells["C3"]
```